# Stream videos opened by script

Tags: linux, stream, vlc, obs

holiday greetings!
I would run stream a videos open by script in one window by any media player (may be VLC). But I don't now how. 
Can you help me, please? Idea is open new video by script (any language) when previous video is ended in one window by any media (linux) player and capture this window in OBS. Example stream like my idea is https://www.twitch.tv/medrybw . MerdyBW streamed by vlc.

Comment: I have idea use flag `--one-instance` for open new video in one window, but how I now a video is end from other process?

Comment: I tried use flags `--one-instance --fullscreen --no-video-title-show` and sleep script by time his length-0.2s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by script on python. Opened next video by:
`subprocess.Popen([path_to_vlc_bin, '--one-instance', '--fullscreen', '--no-video-title-show', video])`
and sleep by duratation video by:
`def get_video_duration(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries", "format=duration", "-of","default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return float(result.stdout)`